VS Code added the local folder as git, how can I disable it again?
I'm using VS Code with git.
Yesterday, I accidentally clicked on the pop-up message, and my local user folder appeared as a git branch. Every time VS Code scans this folder and shows changes (10k+), it loads my laptop, and I don't want upload my local user folder to git.
Suggestion like ".gitignore" not applyable.
How can I disable or detach this folder?
Windows 10x64
VS Code 1.89.0
I looked for it via official documentation and via a Google search, but nothing.

What was "the pop-up message"?

Why is ".gitignore" not applyable?

Did you create a git repository that you don't want in your local user account folder "C:\User..."? Or did you add the folder to an existing git repository?

don't want use all in my local user account folder "C:\User..."

You have a .git folder in your local user folder now. Simply delete it. If you're using file explorer it won't show up and you'll have to select show hidden folders in the option. Then you can delete it. Or if you want to use CMD: Do this

I can't apply it for local USER folder ))

Can't apply what?

Becouse it "C:\Users..." with downloads, docements and others

I said there is a .git folder in "C:\Users" delete .git folder, firstly for check if there is a .git folder there

Thank you for your answer! I'm just deleting the hidden folder ".git"
